# error play framework

Tags: java, playframework

Good evening, I have a problem with my web application in java app, I would like to create a new object "appuntamento", that object is also linked to another object "people." My idea is to initially choose a value for the "people" and then bring it back in the form editAppuntamento.

Here is the code of the controller object "appointment"

```
//show list people
public static Result scegliCliente(int page, String sortBy, String order, String filter, String filterNome, String filterTel, Long idApp) {
        return ok(
                scegliCliente.render(People.pagePeople(page, 25, sortBy, order, filter, filterNome, filterTel), sortBy, order, filter, filterNome, filterTel, idApp));
    }


//redirect to method editappuntamento
public static Result sceltaCliente(Long idCliente, Long idApp) {
        models.Appuntamento app = models.Appuntamento.find.byId(idApp);
        People cliente = People.find.byId(idCliente);

    app.cliente = cliente;

    return redirect(
            controllers.appuntamenti.routes.GestioneApp.editAppuntamento(idApp, idCliente)
    );
} 


//method edit appuntamento
public static Result editAppuntamento(Long idApp, Long idCliente) {
        Form<Appuntamento> thisForm = Form.form(Appuntamento.class).fill(Appuntamento.find.byId(idApp));
        return ok(
            editAppuntamento.render(thisForm, idApp, idCliente)
        );
    }


//save object
public static Result saveAppuntamento(Long idAppuntamento, Long idCliente) {
        Form<Appuntamento> thisForm = Form.form(Appuntamento.class).bindFromRequest();
        if(thisForm.hasErrors()) {
            Logger.debug("form: "+thisForm);
            flash("error","Tipo e Data obbligatori.");
            return badRequest(editAppuntamento.render(thisForm, idAppuntamento, idCliente));
        }

        People people = People.find.byId(idCliente);
        Appuntamento appuntamento = thisForm.get();
        appuntamento.cliente = people;

        if(idAppuntamento == 0){
            appuntamento.save();
        }else{
            appuntamento.update();
        }

        return redirect( controllers.appuntamenti.routes.GestioneApp.list(0,"","","","",""));
    }
```

what is wrong? 
thanks so much

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what's not working.  Do you get an error message? What behavior do you see?  What behavior, exactly, do you want?

Comment: I would make sure to choose the first customer (people) who will then be assigned to the appointment. 
I apologize for my English but I am Italian

Comment: @MirkoVolpi, please, at least put the error message or tell us more about the problem you have. With the actual information very dificult to know what is wrong

Comment: I tried to understand your question for 15 mins. But your question does not provide enough information for us to understand what the issue is and therefore how to look in to it. Your English is not the problem, please read carefully William Price's comment. I don't know what you mean by "choose a value for the people" and "bring it back in the form editAppuntamento", I do not see "people" in the method `editAppuntamento`. The trouble is you have provided a list of methods without telling us the entry point and simply asked us "what is wrong?" but that's the question you should answer to us!